# adding and removing html content on sortable in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am very new to jquery and I am stuck up with one problem . What I want is whenever draggble item is dragged to the sortable items I want html code to be displayed as **drop here** so that user can drop in between the sortable elements my code below id for the sortable element is sort1,sort2,sort3,..... So whenever user drags an item over each of this id only for that perticular time I want it to display drop here .and when dragged away that display block should go .  Is there any way where in I can accomplish this

This is my  [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkitaPalekar/uY95r/1/)  .

```
This is my html code 

  <div  id="sortable">
    <div class="sort" id="sort1">sort1</div>
    <div class="sort" id="sort2">sort2</div>
    <div class="sort" id="sort3">sort3</div>
    <div class="sort" id="sort4">sort4</div>
    <div class="sort" id="sort5">sort5</div>
    <div class="sort" id="sort6">sort6</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with CSS:

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
 visibility: visible !important;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder:after {
  content: "drop here";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uY95r/2/

You'll have to play with the styles to make it look good, but that should get you started.